# Opencv FindCornerSubPix precision

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I need to detect corners on grayscale images with the highest possible accuracy. Currently I am using the OpenCV function: cvFindCornerSubPix().

I prepared a simple test: got an image with a corner of black/white edges:

[image: sample image with detected corner]

and then a series of the same object, moved 1/16pixel each. I did check pixel values manually, test images are just fine.

Detection results were disappointing:
Even though in TermCrit the condition is set to 100 iterations or 0.005 threshold, detection error gets as big as 0.08 pixel.

The graph shows error as a function of position within a pixel. Does not look random at all. Another thing worth a note: for other anular positions of the corner (when edges are not horizontal/vertical) results are better, but still not perfect.

Any idea, how to make this function work properly, why it does not, or what to use instead?

I would greatly appreciate any advice

[image: Error graph]

Comment: Are you sure it's not an effect of the downscaling when you move  the 1/16pixel?

Comment: @Martin Yes, I am. Pixel values on the edge in subsequent images are like: (0, 255), (16, 239), (32, 223),etc

Comment: What interpolation method do you use for the translated images? Try with both bilinear and bicubic. You may be introducing a little bias this way. Try also with translation values that are not inverse powers of two. You can manually verify on the translated image (by linear interpolation of the gray values) that the edges are at their theoretically correct position. Also, try running the iterations  after initializing with the theoretical (true) corner location, and see if it stays stable.

Comment: This is a well known interpolation artifact. From the looks of it, you are using bilinear interpolation. Bilinear interpolation is awful. You need to at least cubic, or even higher order kernels if you want a good result. Take a look at these books:
http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=CAUNJzypCAoC&oi=fnd&pg=PR11&dq=book+subpixel+landmark+detection+and+localization&ots=ka-URzKzdm&sig=7CIMXQKHJ9gBX6GdHbi-ExCtD5U#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Less than 10% of a pixel really isn't bad performance at all. For reference, a correlation peak detector suitable for the production of 3D model from satellite images will have the same order of magnitude of error.

As pointed out in the comments, the exact error pattern will depend on the interpolation method that you use to generate the subpixel pattern. In order to avoid the non-monotonicity introduced by higher-order interpolation methods (beyond order 2), I would suggest the following protocol:

- Generate you input image in a high-res, 16 times bigger;
- Move your target by 1 pixel at a time in this HR image;
- Produce your test images by downsampling (careful: apply an appropriate blurring function like a [PSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function) first if you go for brutal downsampling in order to avoid [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)) to the correct size.

Finally, it is often not desirable to go to a smaller error magnitude. The subpixel corner detector was designed to be used in images where many (typically between 20 and 100) points are detected. These points are then used in a robust estimation process that should remove outliers and average the error on the valid point sets.

Comment: The procedure of generating images is exactly what I used 
and the error is not in pattern generation - it is in the detection

In real, noisy images 0.1 pixel maybe would not be bad ... 
but in perfect, noise-free images I think it should be limited only by color depth (1/256 in 8bit grayscale)

The real application was supposed to be sub-pixel measurements (small displacements on a very precisely calibrated camera)
 - so if I'm getting accuracy of 0.1 on noise-free images it's probably even worse in the real cases

however, I did not check with opencv 2.2 and later as the thread is quite old